# Swift 3 Generics: How to Find The Common Set of Two Generic Arrays

Tags: arrays, generics, swift3

I am trying to find the common set of two generic arrays in Swift 3. I got a type compatibility error with the code below. This happens on the line where I am trying to add an element to the commons array: **"error: cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(T.Iterator.Element)' commonSet.append(lhsItem)"**

What is the solution to this problem?

```
func commonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T]
    where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable,
          T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element
{
    var commonSet = [T]()

    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                commonSet.append(lhsItem)
            }
        }
    }

    return commonSet
}

commonElements([1,2,3], [3,5])
```

Comment: `lhsItem` is of type `T.Iterator.Element`, `commonSet` is of type `[T]` ;) Or to put it another way, if `T` is of type `[String]`, your function says that it's returning `[[String]]`

Comment: Thanks @Hamish that makes perfect sense :D Let me write how I fixed it with your help then.

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise for practice, or because you need it? Because if it's the latter, you're much better using `Set.intersect()`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov just as an exercise. Thanks for your point, I will keep the `Set` class in mind for any future use. Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution for Hashable types

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    func intersect<T: Sequence>(with other: T) -> [Iterator.Element]
    where T.Iterator.Element == Self.Iterator.Element {
        let otherSet = Set(other)
        return self.filter(otherSet.contains)
    }
}
```

That's how I would write this, which contains a few modifications of your code:

1. Instead of writing a global function (or worse, a static function that's arbitrarily nested in some unrelated type) with 2 parameters, you can write it as an extension of `Sequence`. This brings about some nice syntax: `a.intersect(with: b)`, rather than `commonElements(a, b)`.
2. The nested for-loops in your approach lead to `O(N^2)` time complexity. This approach is `O(N)`, but has the additional constraint that `Element` is `Hashable`. A secondary definition can be made that works for non-hashable Elements. It has worse space complexity than yours. Yours is `O(1)`, whereas this is has `O(M)` space complexity, where `M` is the size of the second list.
3. I changed the appending of an initially-empty Array to the filtering of an initially full Array. It's shorter syntax.

## Solution for Comparable types

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Comparable {
    func intersect<T: Sequence>(with other: T) -> [Iterator.Element]
    where T.Iterator.Element == Self.Iterator.Element {
        let arrayA = self.sorted()
        let arrayB = other.sorted()
        var indexA = 0, indexB = 0

        var intersection: [Iterator.Element] = []
        while indexA < arrayA.count && indexB < arrayB.count {
            let a = arrayA[indexA]
            let b = arrayB[indexB]

            if      (a < b) { indexA += 1 }
            else if (b < a) { indexB += 1 }
            else /* implied: a == b */ {
                intersection.append(a)
                indexA += 1
                indexB += 1
            }
        }

        return intersection;
    }
}
```

This solution is slower, with `O(N * log_2(N))` complexity, but still much better than `O(N^2)`. It has space complexity `O(2N)`, because it makes duplicated, sorted copies of both sequences.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, explained very well.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it is my silly mistake. Thanks to @Hamish's comment, I realized that I was trying to build a common set array of type `T` and trying to return it, instead of `[T.Iterator.Element]`. So the fixed version is this:

```
func commonElements<T: Sequence, U: Sequence>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: U) -> [T.Iterator.Element]
    where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable,
          T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element
{
    var commonSet: [T.Iterator.Element] = []

    for lhsItem in lhs {
        for rhsItem in rhs {
            if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                commonSet.append(lhsItem)
            }
        }
    }

    return commonSet
}

commonElements([1,2,3], [3,5])
```